# .htaccess rewrite url to hide a file name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite-module

I am running a project on localhost and my site address is 
`http://localhost/test/a.php/b`.
I wish this url to appear like `http://localhost/test/b` for the users.

a.php is a php file and b is its value.

Below is my `htaccess` file settings :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|robots\.txt)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)a.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ a.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You mean trying it for a week? Have you tried any htaccess rules so far?

Comment: yess a lot but not get the answers

Answer (score 1):

The `RewriteBase` in your htaccess should be set to `/`.

If the url that people can see is

```
http://localhost/test/b
```

Below  rewrite rule :

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ a.php/$1
```

would change the url to

```
http://localhost/test/a.php/b
```

So that the php engine can process it.

User the [HTACCESS TESTER SITE](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to check how rewrite rules work.

Comment: @saquib : Starkeen's answer also works and is complete with file and directory checks.. If none of these solutions work for you, either mod_rewrite is not enabled or your htaccess file is not taken to consideration.

Comment: I tried this htaccess code it also not work sir.I want a.php file to be opened but hidden from url thats it sir so my url will become as  http://localhost/test/b.

Comment: See the edit.. There was a minor mistake in the code.

Comment: @Starkeen: I had to put 'test' in the  tester site to double check it. Corrected it now.

Comment: @saquib: I think you have a bit of misunderstanding regarding the use of htaccess file. If you wish `http://localhost/test/b` to be seen as the url then that should be given as the input to the htaccess file. Changing it to something else in the server side for processing(ie `http://localhost/test/a.php/b` in your case) doesn't mean that the url that people can see will change.

Comment: please do explain then how to write that logic in htaccess file

Comment: @saquib : Please post  the contents of the htaccess file in your question.

Comment: @saquib : What is your `RewriteBase` and `AllowOveride` settings?

Comment: Rewrite base i have changed both / as well as test             and AllowOveride is All

Comment: and your htaccess file  is located in the test folder, right?

Comment: May i know when you put `http://localhost/test/b` in the browser, what error message is that your getting?

Comment: Oh come on !! Please give the exact error message with the error number !!

Answer (score 0):

you can use like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/a.php/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled in Apache?

Comment: @g-v-s-vinayak It is the other way around. Isn't it?